# JavaScript JSON parsing failing with multiple objects from a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Unable to parse JSON when there are multiple JSON objects.

**JSON** File data that works with JavaScript code.

```
{ 
    "name": "Sara",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Female",
    "department": "History",
    "car": "Honda"
}
```

**Javascript Code**

```
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('student.json');
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(student);
```

Adding another student into the JSON breaks the parsing.

```
{ 
    "name": "Sara",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Female",
    "department": "History",
    "car": "Honda"
},
{ 
    "name": "Sara",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Female",
    "department": "History",
    "car": "Honda"
}
```

Which is the correct way to structure the JSON object for multiple students to work with the JavaScript code above?

Reference: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/

Comment: You need array notation, specifically `[ ]` around the list of objects.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. It looks like you just forgot to put objects in Array ```[ {}, {}, ... ]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only valid JSON will be parsed correctly and as you are having more than one object, you should wrap those objects inside `[]` like this:

**student.json**

```
[{ 
    "name": "Sara",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Female",
    "department": "History",
    "car": "Honda"
},
{ 
    "name": "Sara",
    "age": 23,
    "gender": "Female",
    "department": "History",
    "car": "Honda"
}]
```

JS Code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('student.json');
let students = JSON.parse(rawdata);
students.forEach((student) => {
  console.log(student);
});
```